# How can I monitor a python scrypt and restart it in the event of a crash? (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, monitoring

I have a simple python script to send data from a Windows 7 box to a remote computer via SFTP. The script is set to continuously send a single file every 5 minutes. This all works fine but I'm worried about the off chance that the process stops or fails and the customer doesn't notice the data files have stopped coming in. I've found several ways to monitor python processes in a ubuntu/unix environment but nothing for Windows.

Comment: How can you monitor and restart *any* program under Windows?

Comment: If there are no other mitigating factors in your design, my suggestion would be to simplify the script so that it doesn't do the polling; it simply sends the file when invoked, and use Windows Scheduler  to invoke the script on whatever schedule you need. By relying on a core Windows service, you can factor that complexity out of your script.

Comment: @LutzHorn That's kind of what I'm trying to figure out =/ Other then writing another processes that's sole purpose is to monitor the first, I got nothing.

Comment: @bimsapi Thanks for the advice. This was my recommendation exactly to the rest of the team, have task scheduler handle calling the script every 5 minutes and take out the "looping" functionality from with the script itself. Unfortunately I got out-voted and am now stuck trying to find a solution for the "what ifs"...

Comment: @JaySee - bummer. In that case, I'll suggest going in the opposite direction and writing it as a service. The ActiveState Python distribution includes a slew of win32 packages that may be of help. Again, the idea is to piggyback on existing capabilities in the platform (e.g., recovery options for the service)

Comment: @bimsapi after approaching the team again with the issue I have managed to convince them that using Task Scheduler would be the most elegant solution (and the only one that doesn't require an additional process and/or 3rd party application). If you want to make a separate answer I'll select it as the "solved" solution.

Comment: @JaySee - nice that the simpler solution won out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no other mitigating factors in your design or requirements, my suggestion would be to simplify the script so that it doesn't do the polling; it simply sends the file when invoked, and use Windows Scheduler to invoke the script on whatever schedule you need. By relying on a core Windows service, you can factor that complexity out of your script.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out restartme the following link shows how you can use it
http://www.howtogeek.com/130665/quickly-and-automatically-restart-a-windows-program-when-it-crashes/

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'm going to test this out this afternoon. Assuming it's not too intrusive (and works of course) this might be exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @JaySee U might have to make a .exe of the python script